# Use sample keyword within a nested query

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query with the following form:

```
with t1 as (
  select id, col2
  from atable) 
select
  distinct id
from t1
sample 100
inner join t1 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Returns error 3706, `"expected something between an integer and the inner keyword"`

When I comment out the line sample 100 the query runs fine.

My ultimate goal is to get a sample from t1. However, since an ID can appear multipe times in t1, I need to NOT break these up using sample. So, I wish to avoid a sampled data set where the events history of each id is split or has missing entries due to my use of `sample` keyword. In other words, I want to take a sample of IDs, and then use that to filter my table t1.

This way, the events history in t1 for each ID will be complete.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAMPLE is executed after GROUP BY/HAVING/QUALIFY before a DISTINCT operation and ORDER BY. You need to move the sample into the CTE:

```
with t1 as (
  select id, col2
  from atable
  sample 100
) 
select
  distinct id
from t1
inner join t1 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Based on your comment you want to apply the Sample on distinct values:

```
with t1 as (
  select id
  from atable
  group by id -- Distinct is calculated after Sample
  sample 100
) 
select t.*
from atable as t
join t1 
  on t1.id = t2.id
```

If `atable` is large then the distinct operation might use a lot of resources (it's spooled first before the Sample) and a nested Sample should improve performance:

```
with t1 as (
  select id
  from 
   ( select id 
     from atable
                  -- reduce the number of rows for the following Group By
     sample 10000 -- sample must be large enough to have 100 distinct IDs
   ) as t
  group by id -- Distinct is calculated after Sample
  sample 100
) 
select t.*
from atable as t
join t1 
  on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Right, but that will mean that my IDs within t1 will be split. Basically t1 is an events table and I need to sample it but based on userId. I need to keep the full history of each ID if that Id is being kept.

Comment: @DougFir . . . This answers the question that you asked.  I think you should accept this answer and ask another question, with a better explanation of what you really want to do, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GordonLinoff. This is why I added the text ```"My ultimate goal is to get a sample from t1. However, since an ID can appear multipe times in t1, I need to NOT break these up using sample"```. I was attempting to show my train of thought with using ```sample`` keyword, while leaving it open ended for an alternative solution

Comment: @DougFir: It's hard to understand what you want exactly, a sample of 100 distinct userids and all rows for those users?